# Rounding off floating point values

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

While rounding off the floating point values I observed some discrepancy in values. I have extracted following part of code. Here if variable `var_d` is assigned value> 5.3 to then I am getting proper values for variable `var_d`, but for values like 5.01 and 5.02 I am getting 500 and 501 respectively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
double var_d=5.02;
long var_l;
var_l = (double)(var_d*100);
printf("var_d : %f  var_l= %ld\n ",var_d,var_l);
printf("result : %ld\n",var_l);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using GCC Version 4.3.2 on SUSE Linux.

Comment: Rounding up floating point values is bound to a certain degree of unpredictability. Fixed point arithmetics should be used instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: @Alex This has much more to do with the choice of a base than with the choice of fixed/floating point. Binary floating-point fails at these examples. With reasonable parameters, decimal floating-point gets these examples right. Binary fixed-point fails at these or similar examples. With reasonable parameters, decimal fixed-point gets these examples right.

Comment: Indeed it would be nice if C had BCD (binary coded decimal) float types, even if they had to be done in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
double var_d=5.02;
long var_l = rint(var_d*100);
```

Since   100 * 5.02  is not not exactly equal to 502, you are getting a rounded down.

To be clearer: 5.02 has no exact representation in [binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Thus `var_l*100 == 5.02*100` is not exactly 502. In fact it is closer to 501.99999999999994.   When you cast it to an integer, this is rounded down to 501.

Answer (score -1):

```
float var_d=5.02;
long var_l;
var_l = (long)(float)(var_d*100);
```

This should works properly

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, Instead I used following                       var_l = (float)(var_d*100) + 1e-9 ; which is working for now.